# Repeat entire test class in TestNG, with different parameters

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have this code for testing a site with selenium webdriver. There are four `@Test` methods, and a `@DataProvider` with three values. So, in total twelve tests get run.

```
public class SomeTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @DataProvider(name = "URLs")
    public Object[][] createData1() {
     return new Object[][] {
       {"url 1"},
       {"url 2"},
       {"url 3"}};
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    //right now I'm just setting up weddriver for chrome, but 
    //I'll need to run this test for firefox, chrome, and IE
    public void setUpWebDriver(){
        driver = WebDrivers.getChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeWebDriver(){
        driver.quit();
    }   

    //test methods below

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test1(String url){
        //test 1 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test2(String url){
        //test 2 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test3(String url){
        //test 3 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test4(String url){
        //test 4 with url
    }

}
```

Right now, these tests are running under Chrome. But I also want to repeat all of these tests, with all of the data provider variations, on Firefox and Internet explorer. How can I get the entire class of tests to repeat for these other webdrivers? It's almost like I need a `@DataProvider` for the entire class (for the beforemethod).

Comment: I had the same problem when I was using Selenium + TestNG for my web application testing project. I asked for help on the TestNG mailing list and received some, but I never found a solution I really liked.

Answer (score 10):

You should use a [@Factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories).

```
public class SomeTest {

    @Factory
    public Object[] createInstances() {
        Object[] result = new Object[]{            
            new SomeTest(WebDrivers.getChromeDriver())
            // you can add other drivers here
        };
        return result;
    }

    private final WebDriver driver;

    public SomeTest(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "URLs")
    public Object[][] createData1() {
     return new Object[][] {
       {"url 1"},
       {"url 2"},
       {"url 3"}};
    }    

    @AfterClass
    public void closeWebDriver(){
        driver.quit();
    }   

    //test methods below

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test1(String url){
        //test 1 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test2(String url){
        //test 2 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test3(String url){
        //test 3 with url
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLs")
    public void test4(String url){
        //test 4 with url
    }

}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but if I have the test constructor with parameter I get an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null`.

Comment: You should provide the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you are running the test cases from the TestNG.xml file. If yes, you can make use of the `parameters` provided by TestNG and configure the TestNG.xml file to run the test cases as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Internet Explorer Test" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="IE">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.somePackage.SomeTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Firefox Test" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="FF">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.somePackage.SomeTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Chrome Test" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="CH">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.somePackage.SomeTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Some change is required for the `@BeforeMethod` as well.

```
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters{"browser"}
public void setUpWebDriver(String  browser){
    if (browser.equals("IE"))
        driver = WebDrivers.getIEDriver();
    else if (browser.equals("FF"))
        driver = WebDrivers.getFireFoxDriver();
    else if (browser.equals("CH"))
        driver = WebDrivers.getChromeDriver();
}
```